# Как не писать код для каждой из 36 кнопок в WPF в C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click

В WPF присутствует 36 кнопок, при нажатии на каждую, должна изменятся переменная и выводится сообщение.
Есть ли способ не писать по 36 раз в мейне:

```
public void button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        amount += 100;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Message");
    }
```

И при такой возможности, можно ли будет дать каждой кнопке свое сообщение?

**Дополнено:**

Я немного не понял. Можно расжевать?
Будет как то так?

```
<Button Content="1" x:Name="b1" Click="button_Click1" />
<Button Content="2" x:Name="b2" Click="button_Click1" />
```

И на code-befind:

```
public void button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
var b1 = (Button)sender;
amount +=100;
(сообщение через массив)

var b2 = (Button)sender;
amount +=100;
(другое сообщение через массив)
}
```

Comment: Переменная меняется по разному для разных кнопок?

Comment: @Андрей Ну, мне надо будет менять переменную исходя из числа в другой переменной, вроде: amount=+salary. Так что каждая кнопка должна менять переменную на число что будет лежать в salary в тот момент.

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ, вы присваиваете всем кнопкам одно событие, в этом событие создаете переменную, которая из sender получает параметры кнопки, которая вызвала данное событие. Дальше вы можете через if или switch к примеру создать нужные условия (или вовсе вынести все в отдельную функцию и в коде вызывать только ее, передавая имя кнопки, что то вроде: `var btn = (Button)sender; if (btn.Name == "b1") действие`, получать параметры кнопки достаточно всего раз!

Comment: @aret, тогда запишите свое сообщение в свойство `Tag` кнопки и в обработчике (едином для всех кнопок) извлекайте его и показывайте пользователю. Либо используйте команду и `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кто вам мешает вешать обработчик на один и тот же метод?

```
<Button Content="1" Click="button_Click1" />
<Button Content="2" Click="button_Click1" />
```

И на code-befind:

```
public void button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var thisButton = (Button)sender; // Кнопка, которая была нажата
    ...
}
```

Но еще лучше - почитайте про `MVVM` и используйте темплейты и биндинги.

Comment: А как таким образом дать каждой кнопке "свое" сообщение?

Comment: @Ep1demic, например, положить сообщения в массив, по нажатой кнопке определять какое сообщение показать и все

Comment: ...если уж присоединять обработчик так к контейнеру

Comment: @Ev_Hyper какому контейнеру? Не вижу в условии никаких контейнеров.

Comment: @AGS17 Grid, StackPanel,..очевидно-же

Comment: @Ev_Hyper с каких пор у `Grid` и `StackPanel` появились обработчики клика? `O_O`

Answer (score 3):

В WPF есть маршрутизируемые события, благодаря этому вы можете присоединить обработчик к контейнеру, но обрабатывать клики по кнопкам, например:

```
<StackPanel Button.Click="StackPanel_Click">
    <Button Name="b1"
            Content="1"
            Tag="Message1" />
    <Button Name="b2"
            Content="2"
            Tag="Message2" />
    <Button Name="b3"
            Content="3"
            Tag="Message3" />
</StackPanel>
```

в коде

```
private void StackPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
   MessageBox.Show(btn.Tag.ToString());
}
```